# Travis-Ci: launch build daily

Tags: travis-ci

How can I set up a Travis-CI to run build everyday?
It's a JavaScript front application in GitHub. Here's my travis script:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "10"
  - "12"

branches:
  only:
    - master

before_script:
  - yarn install

script:
  - yarn build 

deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip-cleanup: true
  github-token: $GITHUB_TOKEN  
  keep-history: true
  on:
    branch: master
  local_dir: dist/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable this with Travis Cron Jobs:

```
Configure cron jobs from the “Cron Jobs” settings tab on your Travis CI page
```

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/cron-jobs/